# Static header on UWP

Tags: vb.net, xaml, uwp

I'm currently trying to create a header like in the Windows 10 Mobile settings app, which you can see below.

I have tried AppBar and SplitViews, however they do not fit my requirements. How can I create a header similar to this one?

[image: Windows 10 Mobile Settings Menu]

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you just need a control that looks like the header in the Settings app?

Comment: I think so, I'm new to UWP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no control that does that for you, but you can easily create such a header by your own:

```
<Grid
    x:Name="Header"
    Height="50"
    VerticalAlignment="Top">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Viewbox
        Width="50"
        MaxWidth="50"
        MaxHeight="25">
        <SymbolIcon
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Foreground="#FF1BA1E3"
            Symbol="Setting" />
    </Viewbox>

    <TextBlock
        Grid.Column="1"
        Margin="10,0,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Foreground="White"
        Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"
        Text="SETTINGS" />
</Grid>
```